# Python ZipFile извлечение директории с файлами с русскими названиями

Tags: python, python-3.x, кириллица, символы

Вот собственно код никак не могу извлечь файлы и самому директорию на русском языке , а если быть точнее то я в принципе не понимаю как работает open либо `extract()` в `zipfile`. Если просто `extract`, то естественно русские символы не читабельны , если декодируешь то появляется этот символ который не дает извлечь 
 `"/"` так как если принтить `namelist()` то там будет что-то типа того `"Ежегодник 2016/"` и ещё два файла `.doc` внутри тоже с `"/"` на конце. Что с этим всем делать,потому что я читал документацию по `zipfile` но ничего не нашел.

```
#coding: utf-8
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
with ZipFile('ezhegodnik-2016.zip', 'r') as zip:
    for name in zip.namelist():
        print(name)
        unicode_name = name.encode('cp437').decode('cp866').replace('/','')
        print(unicode_name)  
        with zip.open(name) as f:
            content = f.read()
            #fullpath =  os.path.join(os.getcwd() ,unicode_name)
            fullpath = os.makedirs('E:\Learning\programming\Python\Python3/' + unicode_name)
            with open(fullpath,'wb') as f:
                f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот собственно ответ на мой вопрос:

```
import zipfile 
import os
import time 
arh = 'ezhegodnik-2016.zip' 
z = zipfile.ZipFile(arh, 'r')

list_files=list() 
for name in z.namelist(): 
    print '1',name 
    list_files.append(name) 

    z.extract(name) 
    os.rename(name,name.decode('cp866')) 
os.removedirs(list_files[0])
```

Answer (score 6):

[По спецификации](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), zip формат понимает только cp437 и utf-8 кодировки. Реализация [`zipfile` модуля в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) следует этой спецификации.

На практике, были распространены архивы, которые используют OEM code page для установленного варианта Windows. Для русской Винды это cp866.

Если [`shutil.unpack_archive('ezhegodnik-2016.zip', format='zip')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive) не даёт желаемого результата (архив распаковывается, но вы видите кракозябры вместо имён в explorer), то это значит что utf-8 не используется и можно попробовать перекодировать имена файлов из архива из cp437 кодировки в cp866 (вероятный кандидат для однобайтовой кодировки с русским содержимым внутри zip-архива).

Модифицированная (чтобы перекодировать имена) [`_unpack_zipfile()` функция из исходного кода Питона](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a4e3d8f9c37e700402b23fafbfc413e5ca3113d/Lib/shutil.py#L871-L903):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
import zipfile

def unpack_zipfile(filename, extract_dir, encoding='cp437'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as archive:
        for entry in archive.infolist():
            name = entry.filename.encode('cp437').decode(encoding)  # reencode!!!

            # don't extract absolute paths or ones with .. in them
            if name.startswith('/') or '..' in name:
                continue

            target = os.path.join(extract_dir, *name.split('/'))    
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target), exist_ok=True)
            if not entry.is_dir():  # file
                with archive.open(entry) as source, open(target, 'wb') as dest:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, dest)


unpack_zipfile('ezhegodnik-2016.zip', r'c:\kуда\положить', encoding='cp866')
```

Стоит заметить, что [метод `_extract_member()` (реализующий `.extract()`)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a4e3d8f9c37e700402b23fafbfc413e5ca3113d/Lib/zipfile.py#L1519-L1557), выполняет больше манипуляций с именами прежде чем их распаковывать (перенесите код необходимый в вашем случае).

Альтернативно, можно сперва все файлы распаковать и только потом перекодировать их имена (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import zipfile

# unpack the zip archive to extract_dir
extract_dir = r'c:\kуда\положить'
with zipfile.ZipFile('ezhegodnik-2016.zip') as archive:
    archive.extractall(extract_dir)

# reencode all paths in extract_dir
def renamed(dirpath, names, encoding):
    new_names = [old.encode('cp437').decode(encoding) for old in names]
    for old, new in zip(names, new_names):
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, old), os.path.join(dirpath, new))
    return new_names

encoding = 'cp866'
os.chdir(extract_dir) # cd to avoid reencoding the parent dirname
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir, topdown=True):
    renamed(dirpath, files, encoding)
    dirs[:] = renamed(dirpath, dirs, encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3 script to unzip DOS cyrrilic codepage cp866 archive:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import sys

def extract(filepath, directory = '', listonly = False):
  with ZipFile(filepath, 'r') as zip:
    for name in zip.namelist():
      data = zip.read(name)
      unicode_name = name.encode('cp437').decode('cp866')
      type = "DIR" if zip.getinfo(name).is_dir() else "FILE"

      print(type, unicode_name)
      if listonly:
        continue
      if zip.getinfo(name).is_dir():
        continue

      unicode_name = directory + '/' + unicode_name
      dirpath = os.path.dirname(unicode_name)
      if not os.path.exists(dirpath):
        os.makedirs(dirpath)
      f = open(unicode_name, 'wb')
      f.write(data)
  return 0

kwargs = {}
i = 1
while i < len(sys.argv):
  arg = sys.argv[i]
  if arg[0] != '-':
    kwargs['filepath'] = arg
  elif arg == '-l':
    kwargs['listonly'] = True
  elif arg == '-h':
    kwargs['usage'] = True
  elif arg == '-d':
    i += 1
    kwargs['directory'] = sys.argv[i]
  i += 1

argc = len(kwargs)
if argc > 3:
  print("Error: Max. 3 args expected,", argc, "are given.")
  exit(1)

print("Arguments given:", kwargs)

if "usage" in kwargs:
  print("""
Usage: %s [OPTIONS] FILEPATH")
Options:
  -l - list files only
  -d - output directory
""" % sys.argv[0])
  exit(1)

ret = extract(**kwargs)
exit(ret)
```