# Каркозябры в имени файла (используется модуль python: zipfile)

Tags: python-3.x, ziparchive

Всем доброе время суток.
Появился вопрос.

1. Есть файл "текст.txt"
2. Через 7z архивирую его в "1.zip"
   Cкриншот 1:
   [image: Создание архива]
3. Получаю имя заархивированного файла кодом:

   ```
   import zipfile
   import os
   os.chdir(r"E:\Zip_Zip")
   examZip = zipfile.ZipFile("1.zip")
   name_list = examZip.namelist()
   print(name_list)
   str_name_zip = "".join(name_list)
   print(str_name_zip)
   ```

При чтении имени файла (и после разархивации) - получаю презренные каркозябры.
Скриншот: 2
[image: Имя файла - каркозябры]

4. Поискал в интернете.
   По декодеру Лебедева каркозябры - это шрифт CP437
   Пошаманил с charset - для перевода названия в бинарный формат для последующего применения функций модуля codecs

   - добавлял в начало # -*- coding: utf8 -*-

Код полностью.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import zipfile
import os
import chardet
import codecs

os.chdir(r"E:\Zip_Zip")

examZip = zipfile.ZipFile("1.zip")
name_list = examZip.namelist()
print(name_list)

str_name_zip = "".join(name_list)
print(str_name_zip)

# convert to bytes
byte_str = str_name_zip.encode()
print("\n", "Convert to bytes: \n" + str(byte_str))


print("\n", "Use chardet: \n" + str(chardet.detect(byte_str)))

print("\n", "Decode by codecs. Trying... Total:")
new_zip_name = codecs.decode(byte_str, encoding = "cyrillic", errors = "strict")
print(new_zip_name)
```

И результат.
Скриншот: 3
[image: Итог]

Вот сюда:

```
new_zip_name = codecs.decode(byte_str, encoding = "cyrillic", errors = "strict")
```

подставлял в encoding и windows-1251 - нет эффекта.

5. Подозреваю, что дело может быть в способе создания архива. 
   Однако, если создавать оный не через 7z без метода шифрования ZipCrypto, то при работе с таким архивом модуль zipfile выдаёт ошибку при попытке "распаролить" такой архив:
   "RuntimeError: Bad password for file "

**Вопрос: как добиться вменяемых кириллических символов в имени заархивированного файла после разархивации?**

**17.05.2018 в 14:55
Добавлены новые данные и ответы на рекомендации:**

Благодарю за оперативные советы, по порядку:

По замечанию 1: "использовать cp1251" 
При добавлении cp1251 сюда:

```
new_zip_name = codecs.decode(byte_str, encoding = "cp1251", errors = "strict")
```

Результат не тот, что нужен:
Скриншот 4:
[image: Результат cp1251]

По замечанию 2: "ипользовать print(ascii(name_list[0]))"
Нужны пояснения, возможно, пользуюсь этим способом не верно.
Выдаёт строку ascii: \u0393\xd1\xac\xdf\u0393

При переводе этой строки в utf-8

```
asc_str = ascii(name_list[0])
print("ascii string ---> utf-8, result: ", u"\u0393\xd1\xac\xdf\u0393")
```

получаю тот же результат:
Скриншот 5:
[image: ascii]

2-3. По вопросу: "какая ошибка выдаётся..."

Моя вина, надо было изначально написать, что мне нужно, а не выдавать информацию по кусочкам.
Итак, поставил себе задачу написать мини-программу на Python, которая делает следующее:

1. В папке есть n-ое количество зашифрованных архивов (пароль мне известен) с файлами "кириллические_символы".txt
2. Я беру эти архивы, "распароливаю" и разархивирую.
3. Затем архивирую обратно - но уже без пароля.
4. Профит ))

Код распаковщика/разархиватора-запаковщика.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import zipfile
import os

os.chdir(r"E:\Zip_Zip")

# decrypting files
for one_zip_arch in os.listdir("."):
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(one_zip_arch, "r")
    zip_file.setpassword(b"12a")
    zip_file.extractall()

    zip_file.close()
    print("Unzipping compete")


    # get in zip files
    writing_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(one_zip_arch, "w")
    for unz_file in os.listdir("."):
        if unz_file.endswith(".txt"):
            writing_zip.write(unz_file)
        zip_file.close()
    print("Zipping end")


    # deleting files
    for deleting_files in os.listdir("."):
        if deleting_files.endswith(".txt"):
            os.remove(deleting_files)
    print("Done deleting file, after zipping")

print("Complete!")
```

При тестах, если я создаю именно запароленные архивы через стандартный архиватор zip:
Скриншот 6:
[image: simple_zip]

то при попытке "распаролить" такой архив получаю ошибку:
"RuntimeError: Bad password for file "

Скриншот 7:
[image: extract_error]

На stackoverflow.com писали, что поможет использование метода шифрования ZipCrypto:
Скриншот 8:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и это действительно помогло.

Но столкнулся с проблемой кирилличиских символов после распаковки.

Comment: cp1251 попробуйте

Comment: добавьте в вопрос `print(ascii(name_list[0]))`

Comment: связанный вопрос [Python ZipFile извлечение директории с файлами с русскими названиями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654387/23044)

Comment: по одной проблеме за раз лучше исправлять. Если у вас шифрование не работает (RuntimeError), то сперва на файлах с именами в ascii диапазоне научитесь работать. Если проблема с кодировкой (кракозябры), то попробуйте без шифрования с русскими буквами научиться работать. Если по отдельности шифрование и русские буквы работают, тогда уже имея рабочий код по отдельности, пытаться исправить для совместный случай.

Comment: проблема с кодировкой у вас та же, что и по указанной ссылке: `'\u0393\xd1\xac\xdf\u0393'.encode('cp437').decode('cp866')` ->
`'текст'`