# zipfile не понимает кириллицу

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, zip

Такой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import getpass
import os
import zipfile
user = getpass.getuser()
path = r"C:\\Users\\{0}\\Desktop\\".format(user)

zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:       
                if((file.decode('cp1251').split('.')[-1])=='txt'):
                    sek = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
                    zipfile.write(sek)

zipfile.close()
```

Все `.txt` файлы с рабочего стола упаковываются в архив, `Python.zip` , но проблема в том, что названия файлов, где была кириллица, отображается некорректно: `Їєъшш.txt` . Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659475/211923